# DynamoDB Mapper framework for varying attributes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, datamapper, amazon-dynamodb

I recently started using DynamoDB
I see that to use DynamoDB Mapper framework I need to know the name of the attribute before to tie it to a class variable. 
What if I had to implement few dynamically varying attributes but still want to be able to put conditions on them during scan?
I tried binding a hashMap(lets say under variable 'attrMap') in the class and writing my own marshaller to set it. But, I noticed that it is saving as one attribute 'attrMap' in the Dynamo table with a complex value, which doesn't allow me to put conditions on these dynamic attributes during a scan.

Is there a way to set these dynamic attributes at the same level of any other statically binded attributes in the table using Mapper framework which allows me to put conditions on them during a scan?

Comment: try also this DynamoDB object layer (not a mapper): http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have several `Java classes` all annotated with `@DynamoDBTable(tableName="my_table")`

The only thing that common is the `@DynamoDBHashKey`.

Other than that, you can have different classes implement different attributes.
The default marshaller will retrieve only the relevant attributs to each class as well as update only those and won't affect the others when using `SaveBehavior.UPDATE` in your mapper.